# javascript method works localy but not on server

Tags: javascript, asp.net

The following JavaScript method works perfectly fine on local machine, but returns an error after uploading it to GoDaddy server:

```
//add to saved profiles
function addFav() {
    /* opens a dialog */
    $("#addFavourite").dialog("open");
    /* error occurs in the next line */
    var profileName = document.getElementById("MainContent_lblMainName").textContent;
    SendMessageWebService.saveProfile(profileName);
};
```

i'm using google chrome browser for debugging

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Maybe you don't have an element with id `MainContent_lblMainName` on the live version?

Comment: Have you uploaded (or linked to) jQuery? You might be using a local copy of it so it's running fine, but when you upload your site, it'll try and load your local version.

Comment: @peroija This time... :D

Answer (score 0):

Try using the innerHTML property of the label. Are you referencing the right javascript files? it would be better if you referenced the lblMainName programatically:

```
var profileName = document.getElementById("<%= lblMainName.ClientID %>").InnerHTML;
```